# Offline file transfer between Android device and iPad without using an intermediary computer/tablet

Tags: ipad, android, file-transfer

How I can transfer some files from my Google Pixel 6 (running Android 12) to my iPad Generation 9 tablet (running iPadOS 15.7) without using Internet connectivity or a third-party computer/tablet as an intermediary?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be getting a USB-C pen-drive to accomplish the file transfer/exchange.

You'll find pre-installed/first-party file manager apps on both iPadOS and Android which can be used to move/copy files between the device and the connected storage device.

You can refer to the support articles from Apple and Google linked below to learn more:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/ipad1c415e32/ipados
- https://support.google.com/files/answer/9301516